# JSP Radio button not getting selected properly

Tags: java

If cfiType in if I'll set "Female" value through session then it's getting select properly radion button but same thing with I'll set "Male" on given varibale the it's not getting selected?
Below is my code

```
    <%
    String cfiType= (String)session.getAttribute("sex");
    String checked = "";  
    if(cfiType.equals("Male"))   
    {  
    checked = "checked";      
    } 


    %>  
    <input type="radio" name="Male" value="Male" <%=checked%>        onClick="javascript:makeChoice()"/>Male<Br/> 
    <%   
    checked = "";  

    %>  

    <%   

    if(cfiType.equals("Female"))  
    {  
    checked = "checked";  
    }  
    %>  
   <input type="radio" name="Female" value="Female" <%=checked%>    onClick="javascript:makeChoice()"/>Female<Br/>
```

Comment: try to print debugging statement that will show that value of cfiType:
System.out.print("##"+cfiType+"##"); and make sure it match the case your are checking in if statement and contains no spaces at beginning/end or try to use cfiType.trime().equalsIgnoreCase("male");

other thing is when use radio button in HTML , make sure both input have same name attribute , so you can not select both inputs male & female at same time !

Comment: you welcome, please share your answer and accept/close the question if you got your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code. Only thing that could happen is cfiType may be null or not equal to Female.You may simply debug variable using System.out.println(cfiType). Using console logs is not recommended in production.